# Microsoft Graph API: License assignment time without utilizing audit logs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to get the license assignment time for each license assigned to each user in a tenant. Using the audit logs I'm able to fetch this data but its partial in nature as the audit logs are retained for 30 days by default, so I can't get the time of license assignment if it happened before this 30 day period.

Is there any other workaround for this using the Graph API only, where I can get the information about license assignment time for each user and their assigned licenses irrelevant of the assignment period

Comment: Please try the below query let us know if it helps `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2020-09-01T00:00:00Z&assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq 'XXX11324bc54e06')`

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity This query will filter out the users that have been assigned any licenses but I'm interested in the assignment time of these licenses without going the path of audit logs.

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,displayName,assignedLicenses,assignedPlans`.

Comment: In this above query, you get the data of assigned licenses, assigned plans of the user, and their assignedDateTime, but currently, you cann't filter assignedplans by graph api needs to handle through code  (in general, only those properties where the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) says "supports $filter" can be filtered). So you can raise the [UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) if you want to $filter to support assigned plans

Comment: Hey @GovindSharma-MSFTIdentity my issue isn't resolved yet as the assignment time is specific to the service plans and not to the license itself. The assignment time of service plans doesn't necessarily be the same as the assignment time of the license. A service plan can be assigned at a later point of time, also they can be revoked and reassigned so this timestamp will only reflect the last updated values. I hope I haven't interpreted this field incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,displayName,assignedLicenses,assignedPlans
```

In this above query, you get the data of assigned licenses, assigned plans of the user, and their assignedDateTime, but currently, you cann't filter assignedplans by graph api needs to handle through code (in general, only those properties where the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) says "supports $filter" can be filtered). So you can raise the [UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) if you want to $filter to support assigned plan